# Adding user in AD using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, powershell-remoting

I want to create a new computer and want to add that computer in AD domain. Below is the script i want to execute.
Can someone tell where should create *credential object for SRV1* in Domain Controller or in Computer?
If i should create *credential object for SRV1* in Domain Controller than how Computer will get value of *CredSRV1* which is used in *Joining the computer to the domain*?

```
#Creating a new computer in the domain
$NCHT = @{
    Name = 'User'
    DNSHostName = 'user.domain.com'
    Description = ''
    Path = 'OU=xyz,DC=domain,DC=com'
}
New-ADComputer @NCHT

#Creating a credential object for SRV1
$ASRV1 = 'SRV1/Administrator'
$PSRV1 = 'P@SSW0RD'
$PSSRV1 = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $PSRV1 -AsPlainText -Force
$CredSRV1 = [pscredential]::New($ASRV1,$PSSRV1)

#Creating a script to join SRV1
$SB = {
    $ARK = 'domain/Administrator'
    $PRK = 'P@SSW0RD'
    $PSRK = ConvertTo-SecureString - String $PRK -AsPlainText -Force
    $CredRK = [pscredential::New($ARK,$PSRK)
    $DJHT = @{
        DomainName = 'domain.com'
        OUPath = 'OU=xyz,DC=domain,DC=com'
        Credential = $CredRK
        Restart = $false
        }
        Add-Computer @DJHT
}

#Joining the computer to the domain
Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value '*'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName SRV1 -Credential $CredSRV1 -Force

#Restarting SRV1
Restart-Computer -ComputerName SRV1 -Credential $CredSRV1 -Force

#Viewing the resulting computer accounts for domain
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties DNSHostName, LastLogonDate | Format-Table -Property Name, DNSHostname, Enabled
```

**I want to create a new computer and want to add that computer in AD domain. Below is the script i want to execute.
Can someone tell where should create *credential object for SRV1* in Domain Controller or in Computer?
If i should create *credential object for SRV1* in Domain Controller, than how Computer will get value of *CredSRV1* which is used in *Joining the computer to the domain*?**

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-computer?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: how can this help me in the script?
i want to know how Computer that i want to add to a domain will get value of CredSRV1?

Comment: The credentials come from the domain server.  So first you have to add the machine to the domain before you can get credentials

Comment: @jdweng  A credential object is created in domain controller. $CredSRV1 is in Creating credential object. Now i need value of CredSRV1 in my machine(PC) to attach it to a domain! How should i do it?

Comment: It should be automatic.  Once you are part of a domain all credentials requests go to the domain password server and then the credentials are recognized by all machine in the domain.  What is not automatic is the access list to folders on shared drives.  If you are trying to access a folder on new machine remotely you may need to change permission and add a group to the folder.

Comment: Please change the title of your question, since it has nothing to do with adding an AD **User**, but is all about adding a **Computer** and joining that to your domain.